# jquery toggle another ID's css when hovering on another element with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

When hovering over a div with `id="single-main"` how could I get the text color of the matching ID's in the ul with `class="contract-list"` text to change color?

I have seem many examples of hover and on. However none that pass an ID.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="single-main" class="clearfix">                    
    <a id="postID" href="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/" title=" "><img width="112" height="150"     src="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/X.jpg" class="some class" alt="" title= "" /></a>
    <a id="postID2" href="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/" title=" "><img width="112" height="150" src="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/X.jpg" class="some class" alt="" title= "" /></a>    
</div>

<ul class="contract-list">
    <li>
        <a  id="postID" href="http://www.xxxxxx.xx/" rel="bookmark" title=" "> ADVERTISING</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  id="postID2" href="http://www.xxxxxx.xx/" rel="bookmark" title=" "> ADVERTISING2</a>
    </li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Can you post html, it will help us.

Comment: You can't use same id twice, `id` meant to be unique.

Comment: IDs should be unique ( = only used once in a document ) http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id

Comment: Noted (ID's should be unique)... just the best way I could illustrate..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

**HTML** (Notice `id's` replaced with `classes` in `ul`'s `a` tags)

```
<div id="single-main" class="clearfix">
    <a id="postID" href="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/" title=""><img width="112" height="150" src="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/X.jpg" class="some class" alt="" title= "" /></a>
    <a id="postID2" href="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/" title=""><img width="112" height="150" src="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/X.jpg" class="some class" alt="" title= ""/></a> 
</div>

<ul class="contract-list">
    <li>
        <a  class="postID" href="http://www.xxxxxx.xx/" rel="bookmark" title=" "> ADVERTISING</a>
    </li>
   <li>
       <a  class="postID2" href="http://www.xxxxxx.xx/" rel="bookmark" title=" "> ADVERTISING2</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#single-main a').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).css('color', 'red');
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).css('color', 'black');
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ppHWZ/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Although I strongly disagree with your coding techniques as they are in violation with W3C standards. I will use your HTML to provide a working demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/c3rfq/4/

I used This javascript to look inside each of the div and ul that you defined. In this way, you can add as many images and links as you want following your pattern, but I do highly suggest you use classes instead of ids

```
$('div#single-main a').hover(function(){
    $('ul.contract-list #'+$(this).attr('id')).css('color','red');
},function(){
    $('ul.contract-list #'+$(this).attr('id')).css('color','');
});
```

To get a much better `standards-based` answer I would look at the other answers. I just wanted to show a "working" example with what you have given us.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean and I should not use same ID twice :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data-` attributes...

```
<div id="single-main" class="clearfix">                    
    <a data-id="postID" href="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/" title=" "><img width="112" height="150" src="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/X.jpg" class="some class" alt="" title= "" /></a>
    <a data-id="postID2" href="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/" title=" "><img width="112" height="150" src="http:www.xxxxxx.xx/X.jpg" class="some class" alt="" title= "" /></a>    
</div>

<ul class="contract-list">
    <li>
        <a id="postID" href="http://www.xxxxxx.xx/" rel="bookmark" title=" "> ADVERTISING</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="postID2" href="http://www.xxxxxx.xx/" rel="bookmark" title=" "> ADVERTISING2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use the following script...

```
$(function(){
    $("#single-main").on("mouseenter", "a", function(){
        $("#"+$(this).data("id")).css("color", "red");
    }).on("mouseleave", "a", function(){
        $("#"+$(this).data("id")).css("color", "");
    });
});
```

And here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZLEQw/